# Python graph segmentation

Tags: python, point-clouds, lidar

I am trying to detect an open door using LIDAR. I have 270 degrees LIDAR read and I'm trying to detect the door from the graph:

[image]

The door is the peak between 100 and 150.
[image]

The door is between ~30 and ~40.

[image]

Here there is a "noise" spike.

I can see that there is a huge spike in the graph where the door "starts" and "ends". I wondered if the is a scipy/numpy or other library function that can detect this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using `scipy.signal.find_peaks` and fiddling with the input parameters? If you can post some sample data, I'd try it myself to see if that can get you anywhere.

Comment: I tried to use it but I couldn't find good parameters that will match all cases (e.g. different widths and prominences). I uploaded the data as npy files to https://github.com/hadarshavit/Lidar Thanks! Edit: The answer of @mbostic seems to work (I'm still testing it)

Comment: I added my solution below, but I just have a follow-up question: do you want to mark the center of the door or the edges?

Comment: Thanks! I want to detect the center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a function for this, your problem is kind of specific.
But, I think it wouldn't be hard to detect this manually, since other parts of the detection don't have such high derivatives.

You can do something like this:

```
dx = 2
dy = 4

spike_start = None
spike_end = None

for i in range(len(points)):
    # Detect high derivative when spike starts
    if spike_start is None and points[i] - points[i-dx] >= dy:
        spike_start = i

    # Detect high negative derivative when spike ends
    if spike_start is not None and points[i-dx] - points[i] >= dy:
        spike_end = i
        break

if spike_start is not None and spike_end is not None:
    print(f"Door is between {spike_start} and {spike_end}")
else:
    print("Door not found")
```

Play with `dx` and `dy` to properly detect the spike.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at data like this, it is somewhat noisy for a peak-finding algorithm, but I suggest playing around with the following procedure, where the peak finding is done on a smoothed version of the dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

D = np.load('lidar.npy')
D2 = gaussian_filter(D, sigma=3)
A = find_peaks(D2, width=5, prominence=4, distance=10)
```

As you can see, I'm first using your dataset `lidar.npy`, and the found peaks are plotted using

```
for a in A[0]:
    plt.axvline(a)
plt.plot(D2)
plt.show()
```

which marks one peak like this.

[image: lidar.npy]

For the other dataset, using the same parameters, the procedure gives

[image: lidar_d.npy]